# How to get devel content generate module to only include one image per dummy content creation

Tags: debugging

I'm using devel generate and it randomly adds multiple images to articles.

I can limit the number of words in the title.

Is there an option to limit number of images or text lenght?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set the image upload limit in field setting itself.

-Anas